# Density of (ir)rational numbers in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

How do I go about a proof to show that both the set of rational numbers and the set of irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: You can consider a real number $x$ and prove that the sequence $(u_n)$ defined by $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_n =  \frac{\left\lfloor 10^n x\right\rfloor}{10^n}$ converges to $x$ increasingly. This proves that the set of decimal numbers is dense in that of real numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rationals as a dense subset of the reals.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454561/rationals-as-a-dense-subset-of-the-reals)

Answer (score 2):

A set $X$ is dense in $Y$ if every neighborhood of $Y$ contains an element of $X$. In $\mathbb{R}$, any neighborhood is an open interval $(a,b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove that some rational number is in $(a,b)$, choose $n$ such that $1/n < b-a$. Then for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k/n \in (a,b)$.

To show that some irrational number is in $(a,b)$, let $ d = \min \{ | b-k/n | , | a-k/n | \} $. Then choose $m$ such that $\pi/m<d$, and then $k/n+\pi/m \in (a,b)$ and is irrational.

Thus, any neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}$ contains some rational and some irrational, and therefore both the rationals and irrationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

For rational numbers the proof could be as follows.
Lets consider the segment $[a,b)$ for two rational numbers $a, b$. Obviously, $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ is also rational. So, we can split the segment with rational edges into two such segments of twice smaller size. In that way we come to conclusion that if we split every rational segment into parts of size less than $\varepsilon$, than for every segment $S$ of size more than $\varepsilon$ there will be at least one rational number on $S$. The same division works for irrational numbers as well.

Comment: It essentially rests on the definition of the real numbers as the Dedekind completion of the rationals,and that the rationals are order-dense in themselves,and that there is, on Q, a Dedekind cut between any two rationals.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, we can notice that it is always possible to construct a sequence of rational numbers that converges to an irrational number, and likewise also possible to construct a sequence of irrationals that converge to a rational number. This implies that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ = $\mathbb{R}$, and that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}^c} = \mathbb{R}$, implying that both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^c$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

(a)$ y-x>0$,$\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ny-nx>1$.then take $[nx]$ as the largest integer that is $\leq nx$,then $nx<[nx]+1<ny$,so $x<\frac{[nx]+1}{n}<y$.
let this rational number $r=\frac{[nx]+1}{n}$
(b)from (a) we have a non-zero $r\in(\frac{x}{\sqrt2},\frac{y}{\sqrt2})$,i.e $\frac{x}{\sqrt2}<r<\frac{y}{\sqrt2}$
then we have $x<\sqrt{2}r<y$,$\sqrt{2}r$ is irrational,then we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show that $ R $ \ $Q$ is dense in $R $ : Once we know that $Q$ is dense in $R$, take any $r\in (0,1)$ \ $Q $ (e.g. $r=1/\sqrt 2$). For $a<b$ take $q\in (a,b)\cap Q$ . Then take $q'\in (q,b)\cap Q.$ Then $q+(q'-q)r\in (q,q')$ \ $Q \subset (a,b)$ \ $Q.$